# Python -- Help getting a specific value

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

fairly new to python.

i am trying to get the stock price from

```
url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" + readsymbollist[i]
sauce = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(sauce,'lxml')

stockcompany = soup.find('h1', {'data-reactid': '7'}).text
#getcurrentprice = soup.find('span',{'data-reactid': '35'}).text

getcurrentprice = soup.find('span',{'class':'Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)'})
```

that is the class but its not returning anything.

also this code used to work with data-reactid:35 but not anymore. why does datareactid 7 work and yet i dont see that specific span on the page anymore.

Thanks anyone

Comment: depending on which value you have in `readsymbollist[i]` may produce different results, but in the source for `https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/UA` I see only one opening `<h1>` tag that does contain `'data-reactid': '7'`, which is why it works. Maybe check the source once more to ensure you find it. Works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on which element you are trying to get, maybe first start with finding the top-most tag, `'div'` in this case, then find the `'span'` tag, should give the price.

```
# url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" + readsymbollist[i]
url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/" + 'UA'  # example
sauce = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(sauce,'lxml')

stockcompany = soup.find('h1', {'data-reactid': '7'}).text

# find the parent div
div = soup.find('div', {'class': 'Mt(6px) smartphone_Mt(15px)'})
```

results:

```
print stockcompany           # UA - Under Armour, Inc.

# find the 'span' tag inside the div from previous step
print div.find('span').text  # 14.74
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

See documentation of those functions. Probably in the last function you need to escape ('\') special chars, like ",', and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the [pandas-datareader](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader) package, I've used it and found it extremely helpful. It's good at getting stock prices from Yahoo Finance.